# Clang Cross Compiling for Windows Phone ARM target

Tags: windows-phone-8, arm, llvm, clang, cross-compiling

I would like to compile a program written in C using Clang for 'Windows Phone' ARM target.
Does anyone have experience with it?

What is a better approach?

1) Building on a host running Windows 8 using Clang for Windows and MinGW. Does Clang for Windows / MinGW supports ARM by default? If not, I will need to re-build Clang and MinGW?

2) Building on a Linux/MAC host (where ARM target comes as default) and using Windows Phone toolchain (where can I get it?).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Windows Phone ARM target" support in clang. Even if you'd succeed to compile something, I doubt you will be able to link & execute the binaries.