# What is the Windows RT on ARM native code calling convention?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, arm, calling-convention

I couldn't find any documentation on the Windows RT on ARM calling convention used by Visual Studio C++. Is Microsoft using ARM's [AAPCS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf)?

If Microsoft is using the AAPCS/EABI for Windows RT on ARM, is it also using [ARM's C++ ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0041d/IHI0041D_cppabi.pdf) (which is derived from the Itanium C++ ABI)? Maybe even the [ARM exception handling ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0038a/IHI0038A_ehabi.pdf)?

Does the calling convention used by Windows RT on ARM differ from that used by other (embedded) ARM Windows variants?

Is there a reliable way to detect Windows RT on ARM through predefined compiler macros?

*Update: Added the question regarding the C++ ABI.*

Answer (score 8):

Unlike Windows CE (which uses original [APCS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/BGBGFIDA.html) aka Old ABI), Windows RT on ARM uses EABI. More specifically, the variant which uses floating-point registers to pass floating-point data and 8-byte stack/argument alignment.

If I take the following function:

```
int g(float x) {
  return x;
}
```

and compile it with VS2012's ARM compiler, I get the following assembly:

```
|g| PROC
    vcvt.s32.f32 s0,s0
    vmov        r0,s0
    bx          lr
    ENDP  ; |g|
```

You can see that it's using `S0` and not `R0` for the argument.

The one from VS2008 (which can be used to target older Windows CE versions) produces this:

```
str     lr, [sp,#-4]!
ldr     r3, =__imp___stoi
ldr     r3, [r3]
mov     lr, pc
bx      r3
ldr     pc, [sp],#4
```

This code is calling a helper function to perform the conversion.

The Windows CE compiler shipped with Windows Compact 7 supports both the old calling convention (called "cdecl" by MS) and EABI. See [What's New in Platform Builder 7](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/A/24A36661-A629-4CE6-A615-6B2910A1367A/What%27s%20New%20in%20Platform%20Builder.pdf).

**EDIT**: just now noticed you added a question about C++. Microsoft does not use Itanium-style C++ ABI, since their implementation predates it. You can read about Microsoft's implementation in my OpenRCE articles ([1](https://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21), [2](https://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23)) and the follow-up [Recon presentation](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=704). See also the original description from the designer Jan Gray: [PDF](https://www.openrce.org/articles/files/jangrayhood.pdf).

Comment: +1 For a real answer with references to vendor documentation.

Comment: Is there any way to force the VS2012 ARM to make the calls in the old fasion ? (using R0)

Answer (score 3):

I can only answer the 2<sup>nd</sup> question.

> Does the calling convention used by Windows RT on ARM differ from that used by other (embedded) ARM Windows variants?

There are actually three concept that should be understood.  One is the *ARM Procedure Call Standard*, another is the *Language ABI* and a third is the *system call* convention.  Briefly, the *ARM Procedure Call Standard* describes register use in a prologue/epilogue.  The *Language ABI* describe how language variables are passed.  Ie, a **double**, a **long long**, the *this* pointer, `dynamic_cast<>`, etc.   The first is needed to interface assembler with the compiler, the 2<sup>nd</sup> is needed for compiler interoperability.  The 3<sup>rd</sup> is how OS calls are made.

### ARM Procedure Call Standard

The [apcs.txt](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~theom/riscos/docs/CodeStds/APCS.txt) document helps to understand some of the ARM variants.  There are 16 variants based on four different choices.

1. 32 bit vs 26 bit PC - all post 2000 version will use 32 bit.
2. stack limit checking - possibly re-phrased as MMU or no MMU.
3. floating point - supported on most CPU after approximately 2005.
4. Re-entrant vs non-re-entrant - a pure software choice; shared libraries?

So while there are sixteen theoretical variations, for modern systems using an MMU there are only two.  The [Debian ARM hard float](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort) wiki gives information that some Linux/gcc distributions have under went.  I would guess that Window RT is using **hard float** as they would not want to pay a performance price to support outdated hardware.  Finally, it is hard to think that *shared library* or **DLL** support wouldn't be present in Window RT.  So the *ARM Procedure Call Standard* seems to be identical to a *Linux hard float* ABI.

### 'C/C++' ABI

The [**AAPCS**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) defines how languages are meant to map high level function/methods to low level details.  Name mangling ensures that symbols has canonical names so that cross tool linking is possible.  **AAPCS** tools should theoretically inter-operate, but issues may appear with *support libraries* and other system level interfaces.

### OABI/EABI

The [Embedded ARM](http://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/EABI_vs_OABI) wiki gives some information on this standard.  An OS using an MMU will use some calls to transition from *user mode* to *system mode*.  Generally, these are *library* only features and are not part of the compiler.  However, you can certainly find some ARM systems that use the **OABI** convention.  As Microsoft is late the ARM game, they will either use the **EABI** or invented something new.  For instance, calling `malloc()` with a *gcc linux hard-float* compiler will not work as the system calls will be completely different.  Generally you will have to compile with `-nostdlib` and invent your own *C-library*.

I have googled a little bit to find specifics on Visual C++.

- [MSDN on ARM Windows CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933779.aspx)
- [SO ARM calling conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/arm-to-c-calling-convention-registers-to-save)
- [SO on Mingw ARM compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315305/clang-cross-compiling-for-windows-phone-arm-target)

So to answer your 2<sup>nd</sup> question, there are a lot of compilers/systems that will generate similar prologue/epilogue.  If the Visual C++ uses the **AAPCS**, then it can inter-operate with other **AAPCS** compilers.  You may have to create *custom* libraries to get another compiler to call *Windows RT* system calls.  The other questions **should be** answered in a manual.

**Edit:** [GCC's ARM -mabi](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/ARM-Options.html) selects the **ABI**. *aapcs-linux* is *AAPCS/EABI*, *apcs-gnu* is the *OABI* defining [prologue/epilogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) and argument mappings. Compiler configuration select the target OS and instruction/back-end/CPU type; so we have compilers with different names, like `arm-linux-eabi-gcc`, arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for providing some info on ARM calling conventions and ABIs, but if I'm not missing anything, you haven't really answered any of my questions. You're basically saying that Visual C++ may or may not use the AAPCS when compiling for Win RT on ARM, and that these questions should be answered in "a manual".

Comment: That is mainly correct.  I provided a means to answer the question *Does the calling convention used by Windows RT on ARM differ from that used by other (embedded) ARM Windows variants?*  Most likely the prologue/epilogue is the same.  The *language ABI* and *system interface* maybe different.  I guess I am saying that *calling convention* is a little over-loaded.  What is the larger intent?  Even if different compilers use the **AAPCS**, the `svc` interface may change and libraries will not be compatible.  I did not *fully* answer the question, I was trying to prompt a better question.

Comment: A larger intent is **1.** Interfacing with assembler, **2.** Providing binaries for Libraries/DLLs, **3.** Drop-in compiler replacement.  I am just showing what needs to match to fit those goals I guess you are interested in.  In some ways, you can *shoe-horn* a compiler to fit the 3rd goal from the 2nd.